# Laravel api. Как сделать необязательный роут

Tags: php, laravel, api, route

Подскажите, как в Laravel сделать route как тут: 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_page=3&_limit=2

Можно обратиться и без `_limit=2` и без `?_page=3&_limit=2`

Код, как я сделал:

```
Route::get('/articles/_page={currentPage?}&_limit={limit?}', "Controller");
```

Пробывал вот так:
`/articles?_page={currentPage?}&_limit={limit?}`. 
 Да и другими разными способами, не знаю как объявить эту вторую часть как не обяз. параметр

При `/api/articles...` не обращается.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что это не разные роуты?

Comment: Не знаю, может и разные. Но, почему-то уверен, что это можно гибко через 1 route и контроллер реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маршрут для пагинации `articles` может быть один, все остальное (page, limit) отлавливаете через `request()` с обязательной валидацией:

```
// routes\api.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'V1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/articles', 'ArticlesController@index');
});
```

Пишите scope для модели, можете в трейт вынести:

```
public function scopeAdvancedFilter($query)
{
  $data = $this->validateAdvancedFilter(request()->all());

  return $query->paginate($data['limit']);
}

protected function validateAdvancedFilter(array $request)
{
  $request['limit'] = $request['limit'] ?? 15;

  $validator = validator()->make($request, [
    'limit' => 'sometimes|required|integer|min:5',
    'page' => 'sometimes|required|integer|min:1',
  ]);

  return $validator->validate();
}
```

В контроллере:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

...

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
  $articles = Article::with([
      'categories:categories.id,categories.title,categories.slug',
      'user:users.id,users.name',
    ])
    ->advancedFilter();

  $collection = ArticleResource::collection($articles);

  return $collection->response()
    ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
}

...
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Сейчас буду разбираться. Такой ответ даже лучше)

Comment: https://medium.com/@dinotedesco/using-laravel-5-5-resources-to-create-your-own-json-api-formatted-api-2c6af5e4d0e8

Comment: Не подскажешь еще один момент, у меня получается вот так вот: https://imgur.com/a/b3QCHbj . Как вывести без data [..

Вот так пробывал: ArticleResource::withoutWrapping(); - бесполезно.
Index полностью как в ответе

Comment: В ArticleResource прописывается `public static $wrap = null;`, НО пагинация всегда будет обёрнута в `data`, чтобы отдельно было от `meta`

Comment: Вообще, вот [спецификация](https://jsonapi.org/format/)

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое. И последний задам. Таким способом корректно будет делать к примеру "Показать больше", вместо пагинации? 
То есть page = 1 , а limit +=4 к примеру, при клике на кнопку

Comment: Так: page=1&limit=8, page=1&limit=12 ?) Повторы будут.

Comment: Не подскажешь, то думаю ради короткого ответа нет смысла новую тему.
Мне нужна к примеру /api/articles?filter[popular]=true&limit=5 , и чтобы не advancedFilter срабатывал, а другая scope модель (popularFilter) при этом запросе в index. Как это можно сделать? То, у меня только в голову приходит через if($articles) 
..->popularFilter();
- в контроллере. Есть ли способ встроенный попроще?

Comment: Как раз таки лучше вопрос задать. Что сделано, как реализовано, что работает и что должно получиться?

Comment: Задал вопрос, хотелось бы от вас услышать. Спасибо