# Laravel api. Гибко сделать несколько api-route в одном методе

Tags: php, laravel, api, route

В одной из тем получил ответ на вопрос 
[Laravel api. Как сделать необязательный роут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977178/laravel-api-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82)

Доп. вопрос к той теме.
Мой контроллер (index метод), срабатывает при `api/articles?limit=5`

```
  $publications = Publication::with([
        'user:users.id',
    ])->advancedFilter();

    $collection = PublicationResource::collection($publications);

    return $collection->response()
        ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
```

модель scopeAdvancedFilter:

```
$data = $this->validateAdvancedFilter(request()->all());

            return $query
                ->where('is_active', true)
                ->paginate($data['limit']);
```

Как мне к примеру сделать чтобы при параметре `/api/articles?filter[popular]=true&limit=5`
Срабатывала вот эта модель, вместо advancedFilter

```
public function scopePopularPublication($query)
    {
        $data = $this->validateAdvancedFilter(request()->all());

        return $query
            ->where('is_active', true)
            ->latest('amount') //получает самые просматриваемые по полю
            ->paginate($data['limit']);
    }
```

Мне в целом нужно, чтобы с articles можно было проводить разные манипаляции, то есть получить популярные по полю, получить самые новые статьи и т.д 
На ум приходит только, в контроллере делать делать через if, но меня интересует есть ли какой-то встроенный гибкий способ сделать это в контроллере index. 
P.s в одном github проекте нашел, наподобии такого хотел бы:

```
localhost/books?include=chapters,author
localhost/books?include=first_chapter
localhost/books?filter[published_before]=1990-01-01
localhost/books?filter[published_after]=1990-01-01
```

Comment: Не помню, скидывал ли я ссылку на [источник](https://github.com/codekerala/Laravel-5.6-and-Vue.j-2-Dataviewer-Advanced-Filter/tree/master/app/Support)

Comment: @РустамГимранов Спасибо большое. Разобрал большую часть. Может можешь посоветовать какие-то еще репозитории с хорошим кодом, по построению json-api.

Comment: Ну эту [ссылку](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-php) я точно скидывал. Там куча библиотек с гитхаба и также для laravel есть.